# Accessing list from Subsite from SharePoint online using c# CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom

I am using simple console application to pull data from a SharePoint Online list using the following code

```
string siteUrl = "https://MyServer.sharepoint.com/sites/MySiteCollection";
string userName = "myUsername@company.onmicrosoft.com"
var passWord = new SecureString();

foreach (char c in "myPassword") passWord.AppendChar(c);



            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userName, passWord);
            SP.List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Announcements");

            CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
            camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name='ID'/>" +
                "<Value Type='Number'>10</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>100</RowLimit></View>";
            ListItemCollection collListItem = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);

            clientContext.Load(collListItem);

            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

            foreach (ListItem oListItem in collListItem)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ID: {0} \nTitle: {1} \nBody: {2}", oListItem.Id, oListItem["Title"], oListItem["Body"]);
            }
```

However when I run this program I receive the following error

```
Cannot contact web site 'https://myserver.sharepoint.com/' or the web site does not support SharePoint Online credentials
```

When I put the full link of the list in the browser I can access it however when I put in the default site collection url i am getting denied access due to permissions.

Is it possible to pull data from this list if i specifically only have access to the list site or do i need access in parent site?

Comment: Try connecting to the site collection using **App Only Authentication** (Instead of using username and password you have to use Client Id and Client Secret). [Reference](https://www.sharepointpals.com/post/how-to-get-the-client-context-using-app-access-token-by-passing-client-id-and-client-secret-id-using-csom-in-sharepoint-office-365/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to connect to your SharePoint Online site, you must enable **legacy authentication protocols** in your tenant (set LegacyAuthProtocolsEnabled to **TRUE**).

To enable legacy authentication protocols, run the following commands against your SharePoint Online tenant (using PowerShell):

```
Connect-SPOService -URL https://XXXX-admin.sharepoint.com
Set-SPOTenant -LegacyAuthProtocolsEnabled $True
```

where ‘XXXX‘ is your tenant name

**Note**:

- Changes may take up to 24 hours to take effect.

For more details refer to below article:

[https://www.assistmyteam.com/kb/cannot-contact-web-site-https-xxxx-sharepoint-com-or-the-web-site-does-not-support-sharepoint-online-credentials/#:~:text=Cannot%20contact%20web%20site%20'https%3A%2F%2Fxxxx.sharepoint.com,not%20support%20SharePoint%20Online%20credentials&text=This%20error%20occurs%20if%20the,FALSE%20in%20your%20tenant%20settings](https://www.assistmyteam.com/kb/cannot-contact-web-site-https-xxxx-sharepoint-com-or-the-web-site-does-not-support-sharepoint-online-credentials/#:%7E:text=Cannot%20contact%20web%20site%20%27https%3A%2F%2Fxxxx.sharepoint.com,not%20support%20SharePoint%20Online%20credentials&text=This%20error%20occurs%20if%20the,FALSE%20in%20your%20tenant%20settings)).

Comment: That seems to have resolved the issue. Thank you!